# Как начать выполнять функцию в другом потоке? Python

Tags: python, многопоточность

Проблема состоит в следующем. У меня есть функция(view_tasks), в которой есть бесконечный цикл, который прекратит своё выполнение при получении сообщения от пользователя в чат-боте. Мне нужно добавить эту функцию в другой поток, чтобы не загружать бота. Иначе получается так, что бот ждёт выполнения этой функции от конкретного пользователя и не может отвечать другому.

Пример:

```
def view(message, task):
    os.chdir(BASE)
    photo = {'photo': open(f"{task[4]}\{task[1]}", 'rb')}
    text = f"Номер вопроса: {task[0]}. Вам даётся {task[2]} минуты."
    requests.post(f'{URL}{BOT_TOKEN}/sendPhoto?chat_id={message.chat.id}&caption={text}', files=photo)

def wait_answer(message, q):
    answers[q] = "+"
    answer[q] = message.text

def view_tasks(message):
    stop = 0
    for task in tasks:
        if stop == 1: break
        view(message, task)
        printy(message.chat.id, "Введите ответ (число или пара чисел, записанных через пробел)")
        while answers[int(task[0])] == "-":
            if datetime.now() > dt_time_stop:
                printy(message.chat.id, f"Время кончилось. Вариант {number} отправлен на проверку")
                stop = 1
                break
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, wait_answer, int(task[0]))
            time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать класс `threading.Thread`:

```py
from threading import Thread


def f():
    while True:
        pass  # Что-то


t = Thread(target=f)
t.start()
```

Подробнее в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/threading.html#threading.Thread).

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью `multiprocessing.Precess`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

def f():
    print('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Вывод:

```
hello
```

У `Process` есть один плюс:

можно передать аргумент `args`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello, ', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Вывод:

```
hello, bob
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class